# Regular expression using javascript for removing the special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

How to write the regular expression for the below string using Javascript.

```
[Account].&[1]+[Account].&[2]+[Account].&[3]+[Account].&[4]
```

T need the following output format

```
1,2,3,4
```

emoving all the strings and special characters.

Comment: You just want to find numbers? Think about what you want to *match* when trying to build a regex and that will make your life easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/\[(\d+)\]/g
```

That will return you the array containing all numbers in the string, which you then can join using `,` as delimiter.

```
var string = "[Account].&[1]+[Account].&[2]+[Account].&[3]+[Account].&[4]";
var numbers = string.match(/\[(\d+)\]/gi);
alert(numbers.join(','));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick responding, it is very helpful to me,           [Account22].&[1]+[Account65].&[2]+[Account45].&[3]+[Account85].&[4] in this string contain Account22, Account65.....numbers, i need the output only for the 1,2,3,,4, here removes all the characters and numbers expect 1,2,3,4.any solution please

Comment: Then please be so kind as to accept the answer if it was correct for you as soon as you find time to do so. Always good to help :)

Comment: Create another question for that - Or edit your question and add the requirements - then I will add the new expression to my answer.

Comment: var string = "[Account0].&[1]+[Account1].&[2]+[Account2].&[3]+[Account3].&[4]";
var numbers = string.match(/(\d+)/gi);
alert(numbers.join(','));

here output is  : 0,1,2,2,3,3,4

Here I need to eliminate all the strings with numbers and special characters.

can you please help me,is there any solution for the output : 1,2,3,4

Comment: @Rajasekhar I added a second filter to get only these numbers (be careful `map` is not implemented everywhere)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you an array of the extracted numbers:

```
var ar1 ='[Account5].&[1]+[Account6].&[2]+[Account7].&[3]'.match(/\[\d+\]/g);
```

And to assert you extract only numbers between brackets:

```
var ar2 = ar1.map(function (elt) { return elt.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, "$1"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
yourString.replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]', '');
```